# Trying to add filter to searchBar for a collection view populated with type AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift, filter, uicollectionview, searchbar

I'm sorry about the title.  I have a collectionView populated with an array of objects of type (AnyObject).  I'm trying to add search to this. I found a tutorial on it but in the tutorial it is just an array of Strings. I want the searchbar to search based on username. I got everything working except this function:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText:String) {
       self.friendsArrayForSearchResult = self.friendsArray.filter() {
           guard let type = ($0 as AnyObject)["username"] as? String else {
               return false
           }
           return type.rangeOfString("username") != nil
       }
   }
```

Basically if the user is searching, the collectionview is being populated with self.friendsArrayForSearchResult and if the user isn't searching it is populated with self.friendsArray.

Okay so I got it working with this:

```
self.usersArrayForSearchResult = self.usersArray.filter() {
            if let pos = ($0["username"] as! String).lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchText.lowercaseString) {
                return (pos.startIndex == ($0["username"] as! String).startIndex)
            }
            return false
        }
```

But the only thing is I want it to show users who contain what the user is searching for.  So if their name is fred and you type ed then fred comes up...is this possible using this function or do I have to do a bunch of other stuff?

Okay so after being up all night trying to figure this out...apparently this was all I needed to do.

```
self.friendsArrayForSearchResult = self.friendsArray.filter() {
            if ($0["username"] as! String).lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
```

Comment: Why an array of [AnyObject] any object does not have a property called username how can you expect the  ($0 as AnyObject)["username"] as? String to return any value ??? Am I missing something here ???

Comment: Yeah that's the part I'm trying to figure out.  How do you do objectForKey on AnyObject?

Comment: Try down casting it like ($0 as YourObject)["username"] as? String rather then AnyObject

Comment: what is YourObject

Comment: May I know how are you populating self.friendsArray??

Comment: Okay I switched it to [NSDictionary] instead of [AnyObject] and when I print(type) i'm getting a list of the usernames so that seems to be working.  The names aren't coming up though when I search the cells just all disappear so something still isn't right.

Comment: I was populating friendsArray with an array of NSDictionary's from firebase database.

Comment: Are you re-loading the tableView with filtered results ???

Comment: I updated it, got it working.  It is updating.  Only problem is i'm using rangeOfString() but when I type like the end of a word it won't work.. so like if the user name is fred and i type "red" then fred won't come up, unless i actually start with the "f"

Comment: Rather then using range check if you can modify your filter with something like contains :) So when you type red it will check fred contains red and it should be listed as expected :)

Comment: it won't let me.  I tried using containsString() and it says "initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not "bool"